# How to set RSS feed with sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube

Where I can set up RSS feed for my sonarqube 4.5.1 ? I can't find the option anywhere.
I search on the documentation, on the available plugins, and I found nothing at all.
Thanks.

Comment: http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/RSS-Alerts-feed-not-updating-for-one-project-td5017703.html =(

Answer (score 0):

The RSS feature has been dropped in SonarQube 3.7, see [SONAR-4584](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4584).